# PHP headers for excel file not working

Tags: php, excel, mime-types

I have a set of .xls files in a directory with an .htaccess that blocks all access. Then one directory up I have a PHP file which does similar to the following to recover the .xls file and download it. Here is the bulk of the PHP file:

```
<?php
require_once( '../wp-blog-header.php');

if (is_user_logged_in()) {

    $file = "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/files/downloads/{$_GET['name']}";
    if( file_exists( $file ) ) {
        header( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$file}");
        header( 'Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
        readfile( $file );
        exit;
    }

} else {
    die();
} ?>
```

Then the link works like this: http://domain.com/files/file.php?name=excel.xls
If i remove all the headers and just place something like echo "download link here" then it works fine but when I have the header info in there is displays an Error 6 (net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND):

The script works fine for html files with a content type of text/html so the path to the downloads directory is working fine. Is there something specific to excel files I am missing?

Any ideas?

Comment: What is it doing incorrectly? Know that MS office files have and use lots of different MIME types.

Comment: We assume you don't have any other output (even whitespace) before your `header()` calls. Any error messages?

Comment: Also, how are you sending down the file? Simply calling the header with `filename=file.xls` won't send down `file.xls`. You need to stream the file to output.  Please post more code...

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. I have updated my description to detail the situation a bit better.

Comment: Wait, so did you already have `readfile()` in there or did you just add it?

Comment: What is in `wp-blog-header.php`? Does that actually output your blog HTML header, or _any_ output at all?

Comment: Yea i did already have readfile() and exit, I just forgot to put it in the above code sorry. The wp-blog-header.php bit is for WordPress so the is_user_logged_in() will work. It shouldn't make a difference as for the echo test to work the is_user_logged_in() bit must be returning true anyway. I think the problem is definitely somewhere in the headers stuff

Comment: The `{$file}` name should just be a basename, and be quoted in that HTTP header attribute if it contains spaces etc. Also elaborate on the `Error 6 (net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)` - that's not a PHP error message.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski You were right! instead of require_once( '../wp-blog-header.php'); it should have been require_once( '../wp-load.php'); The error was a browser error because it couldn't access the wp-blog-header.php file. Totally works now *headsmack*

Comment: Ok, serious about the path traversal though. Even if you can't limit to .xls and filename patterns, you must at least filter against null bytes and `/../`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski You removed your comment about the best method of doing that. Are you able to re-post it or steer me in the right direction please?